# What determines the minimal degree in a B-Tree?

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I am learning about B-Trees and most of it makes sense but the thing I can't seem to understand is what determines the Minimal Degree of a B-Tree?  In what I find online and the Pluralsight course I viewed it seems like they just picked that number out of the air but I'm sure that there must be a reason or a way to determine that number.

I am also a little unsure of what happens when a child exceeds the number of values allowed for a node.  If I understand correctly the value that exceeds the max number of values per node gets shifted over to the next node with available space?  In the diagram that I created in the link below I did two things:

1. Picked a random number for the Minimal Degree as that's the first part of my question I don't understand
2. Made the left most leaf 6 values which exceeds the most values per node which is 5

[B-Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9EOt.png)

I know that in my diagram that is not how it would work in regards to how I numbered the keys, I did that just to simply show/count the least/most number of values per node.

Anyone who can help explain this would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't get your main question, we choose the degree of the B-Tree, the minimal degree possible is 2, so are you basically asking why they  said 2 "out of thin air" (Pluralsight)?

Comment: Kind of.  I am just asking how or who determines the minimal degree.  So in my example from my diagram I just chose 3 randomly.  I am wondering how to determine what the minimal degree is.  Does it depend on how many items go in the root?  If so how do we determine that number?

Comment: We choose `t`, then we proceed with building the tree, not the opposite, so your original question is how to determine the `t` from a given diagram?  Also, I don't get how numbers above 1 got to its left in your picture.. is there an original question that you can post?

Comment: Yes I guess that's what my question boils down to is how do we choose t.  I'm not sure what you mean regarding the numbers above 1 to the left in the picture

Comment: I think you should read more about B-Trees, the keys are ordered in a non-decreasing order, 6 cannot come to the 'left' of 1 for example. I suggest you go to here: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BTree.html and play around with the simulation

Comment: That simulation is very helpful I think it will clear up some of my confusion, appreciate it